# Let $g$ be a probability density function, what is the ratio $\frac{g(x)}{g(t)}$ for $x>t$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, reference-request

As in the question, I would like to know more about the ratio:
$$\frac{g(x)}{g(t)}$$
for $x>t$ two points in the support of a random variable with pdf $g$.

The first thing I would like to ask is whether this ratio has a name.  It looks like a likelihood ratio, but $g$ is the same bewteen numerator and denominator (whereas properties of likelihood ratio, such as monotonicity, refer to pairs of different distributions, possibly members of a Markov kernel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_likelihood_ratio).

In particular,  I am interested in the behavior of this ratio as $t\to\bar{\theta}$, where $\bar{\theta}$ (possibly $+\infty$) is the upper bound of the support of the random variable described by $g$. It seems to me that, when $\bar{\theta}=+\infty$, $g$ must be eventually decresing, at least under some additional assumptions (think of normal, logistic, exponential) so that, in this cases:
$$\exists\tau\forall x\geq \tau\quad \frac{g(x)}{g(\tau)}\leq 1$$

But is this always true? Can we relate the limit behavior of the ratio to some other property of $g$ (possibly its tail shape)?

**EDIT** I recognize now that the condition I would be interested is:
$$\exists K\exists\tau\forall t\geq \tau\forall x\geq t\quad \frac{g(x)}{g(t)}\leq K$$

Is this also true if $g$ is continuos,positive with unbounded support? It seems to me the answer is yes, it's equivalent to say that $g$ should eventually decrease (at least in some average sense) to have mass 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true for any valid probability density (as long as $g$ is continuous and never takes the value zero).

Continuity is important because we can always take a nice-behaved pdf like the Gaussian, and adjust it over a set of points with zero measure to get a PDF that doesn't strictly have a tail limit.

For example. Let $\phi(x)$ be the standard normal density function. It has nice tail properties and adheres to your conjecture.

Now, lets form the following function

$$Q(x) = x\mathbf{1}_{x \in \mathbb{Z}} $$

Then the function $\psi(x) + Q(x)$ has not limit at either tail, yet it integrates to 1 and all that good stuff, since the domian where $Q(x)>0$ has zero Lebesgue measure.

So if $g$ is a continuous pdf then limits should exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I edited because actually I need something stronger. Do you have any idea also on that?

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta nothing special about K=1; same reasoning applies

Comment: Ok, I see that, but I also added a quantification, now the thing I ask is stronger in my opinion

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta your revised condition can't be true -- assume $\exists K\exists\tau\forall t\geq \tau\forall x\geq t\quad \frac{g(x)}{g(t)}\leq K$ then that implies $\frac{g(t)}{g(t)} \leq K$ which is false for any $K<1$ since we are allowing $x\geq t$. I think if all you want to have that it is eventually monotonic decreasing, you don't need such a complicated assumption.  All you need to assume is that $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 0$

Comment: Of course one could allow x>t without any essential loss. Also, it my well be K>1. Anyway eventually decreasing should work. But then, in my other post, shouldn't I be able to apply dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta -- yes, but this just says it's strictly monotonic -- so exponential, weibull, or any other of your typical distributions satisfy this --  not sure it's an overly useful assumption wrt the bigger problem you are trying to solve. The tricky part about your other problem is that you have this translating gaussian to the limit is sort of invariant to increasing $t$

Comment: Ok but, if I can bound the family of integrands (both the ratio and the density part) I can always apply Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem. The limit of the family is the constant 0, and $I$ should always be 0

Comment: Yes, lets say $K=0.5$ then what do you do with $\varphi$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138008/discussion-between-francesco-bilotta-and-bey).

Comment: Of course you are right, here the space is infinite measure and I cannot bound everything by a constant